# Как измерить время выполнения js скрипта в микросекундах (не в миллисекундах)

Tags: javascript, время

Как засечь время на js в микросекундах? В частности мне надо суммировать время выполнения кусочка кода, который выполняется быстро (менее 1 миллисекунды), но часто.

Comment: стоит перефразировать основной текст вопроса, чтобы он стал вопросом, а не заметкой для себя

Comment: @Grundy Ок. Сделал.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Чтобы измерить время в микросекундах (не миллисекундах) надо воспользоваться стандартной функцией `performance.now()`. Она возвращает вещественное число (время от начала выполнения процесса) в милисекундах, а дробная часть есть соответсвенно микросекунды.

```
var time = performance.now();
// некий код
time = performance.now() - time;
console.log('Время выполнения = ', time);
```

Также можно использовать `console.time('mark')` и `console.timeEnd('mark')` - но тут вывод в консоль и просуммировать полученные отрезки времени не удастся.

[Подробнее тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

Answer (score 2):

В node js это не так просто работает, надо использовать:

`const { PerformanceObserver, performance } = require('perf_hooks');`

Тут более подробно: https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now

Еще есть вариант использовать npm пакет:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now