# Оптимизация setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

На странице есть несколько, в будущем может и будут добавляться, функции ака слушателей, которые выполняются через `setInterval`.

И вот стало интересно, станет ли выше производительность, если всё объединить в один интервал, который будет к примеру проходиться по массиву с функциями и выполнять их все. Вместо того, чтоб каждый раз создавать новый интервал...

Comment: Что мешает протестировать время работы самостоятельно?

Comment: да.. я думал над этим. Но как протестировать время работы сетинтервала

Comment: Запустить таймер в начале работы интервала и посмотреть на время его работы в конце интервала: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/520048

Comment: нужно больше конкретики результат может зависеть от кода, который выполняется по таймеру

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю свою версию происходящего.

Что в вашем понимании производительность?

Вот вы прораб и у вас есть один рабочий Вася. Вася очень любит курить. как часто он будет ходить курить, если вы ему будете подкидывать мелкие поручения??

А если вы попросите сделать его все накопившиеся за один раз?

Аналогия со вкладкой браузера, которой иногда надо отвлекаться от длительных задач, чтобы обрабатывать действия пользователя.

**Upd**

Если серьёзно, то для того чтобы не прерывать взаимодействие пользователя со страницей, длительные задачи лучше выполнять через webworker.

В случае с setInterval, чем дольше выполняется его обработчик, тем дольше вкладка будет не отвечать на запросы пользователя.

Answer (score 0):

Логика подсказывает, что если вместо нескольких задач вы создадите одну, то нагрузка на память и на процессор снизится. Однако, на практике вы эффект скорее всего не заметите, если конечно у вас не 1000 таймеров.